# Checking fillfactor setting for tables and indexes

Tags: postgresql, fillfactor

There is maybe some function to check the fillfactor for indexes and tables? I've tried already \d+  but have basic definition only, without fillfactor value:

```
        Index "public.tab1_pkey"
 Column |  Type  | Definition | Storage 
--------+--------+------------+---------
 id     | bigint | id         | plain
primary key, btree, for table "public.tab1"
```

For tables haven't found anything. If table was created with fillfactor other than default:

```
CREATE TABLE distributors (
    did     integer,
    name    varchar(40),
    UNIQUE(name) WITH (fillfactor=70)
)
WITH (fillfactor=70);
```

Then `\d+ distributors`shows non-standard fillfactor.

```
                            Table "public.distributors"                                                                                                                                        
 Column |         Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description                                                                                                            
--------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------                                                                                                           
 did    | integer               |           | plain    |              |                                                                                                                        
 name   | character varying(40) |           | extended |              |                                                                                                                        
Indexes:                                                                                                                                                                                       
    "distributors_name_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name) WITH (fillfactor=70)                                                                                                               
Has OIDs: no
Options: fillfactor=70
```

But maybe there is a way to get this value without parsing output?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to query the `pg_class` system table:

```
select t.relname as table_name, 
       t.reloptions
from pg_class t
  join pg_namespace n on n.oid = t.relnamespace
where t.relname in ('tab11_pkey', 'tab1')
  and n.nspname = 'public'
```

`reloptions` is an array, with each element containing one `option=value` definition. But it will be null for relations that have the default options.